# How to get raw text of a Handlebars.js block template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to make this work:

```
{{#definePartial "myPartial"}}
  Value: {{value}}
{{/definePartial}}

{{>myPartial this}}
```

But I can't figure out how to get the text from the `definePartial` block helper. All I have is `options.fn()`, that would replace `{{value}}` with a value from the current context.

Is there a way to do this, without using `<script>` or other tag to store the partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
{{{{definePartial "myPartial"}}}}
  Value: {{value}}
{{{{/definePartial}}}}

{{>myPartial this}}
```